# Fetch value from database table where one column of table(foreign key) is equal to input value

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I am using linq to fetch value from database table where one column of table (foreign key) is equal to input value but I am not getting that property when writing linq.

```
var country =
    from x in db.Viewerships
    where x.AssetId == model.ID
    select x.CountryName;
```

In above code `x.AssetId` is not found because `AssetId` is used as foreign key in the table.

Comment: `x.Asset.Id`, maybe ? If you have navigation properties...

Answer (score 0):

When you add the tables in your model, there is checkbox which says "Include foreign key columns in the model", if you didn't tick this option, it will NOT include the Foreign Key Columns in your entity. However it will by default create the navigational property for the other entity, so you have 2 options

1. Either re-add the table with said option ticked
2. Use the navigational property like this

Code:

```
var country =
    from x in db.Viewerships
    where x.Asset.ID == model.ID
    select x.CountryName;
```

Assuming your Asset is the navigational property and Asset table's Primary key column is ID